# How does Vivado ensure that signals do not transition unpredictably when they are sampled by a clock edge and how does this relate to simulation?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, fpga, clock, vivado

I wrote some VHDL code and I wrote a simple sequential code defining a clock sensitive process. Whenever the clock rises from low to high I check another signal in the architecture and I do stuff depending on its value. Nevertheless, this signal transitions at the same time instant as the rising edge of the clock occurs.

In simulation, when the rising edge arises, the system always samples the signal value before its transition. My question is: how does this work out once the code is implemented on the corresponding FPGA? Does it produce unpredictable sampling of the signal value? Do you advice to always avoid this type of scenario within a VHDL architecture?

Comment: The job of the synthesis tool is to ensure that *setup* and *hold* times are not violated. You can research those terms.

Comment: Simulation cycles are ordered. Signal updates are scheduled in a projected output waveform (queue) and are applied before any process resumes and is subsequently suspended. Both a register and input can transition at the same time and it will see the input as valid. Synthesis maps HDL design descriptions to device specific primitives with inherent setup, hold and propagation delays (clk to q, routing etc.).which are checked against timing targets you specify. Do you have an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question?

Comment: Thank you both for the response. I am sorry if I reply now only. However, I think this clarified my perplexities. In fact, the hold time of the sampled signal is not depicted within the output wafeform but now it will be inherently present in the FPGA. (correct me if I'm wrong)